# Email Cron Job With Attachments

Tags: php, mysql, email, ubuntu, cron

My Current setup looks like this:

Stack:

php
mysql
ubuntu server

1. User Inputs an appointment on our site
2. "Email" records are inserted into the database
3. .pdf file is generated on the fly and inserted as an "Email Attachment" record with a path to the file on the server
4. Cron job on **the same** server picks these records up and sends them out via phpMailer

Everything works fine in my current setup, but I can not have this cron job running on the production server as it will bog it down. And so I need to generate the files on the fly save them some how so that **another server** can pick up the email records and attach all the files needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rsync in a cron job to keep files synchonised in both servers and send the e-mails on the other server only when this pdf file exists in it.

After some hours you could delete the pdf in your production server (if you want) and the file will be also removed or not from the other server depending on the way you execute rsync (--delete option).

Comment: I have thought about rsync, I was hoping to have a more elegant solution. And also, how do I know rsync is going to sync the files before the cron job runs?

Comment: Well, you have to check that the pdf exists before sending the pending e-mails, this way you know that the rsync has done its work before. An alarm could also be sent if, for example, it has been 5 minutes since an e-mail should have been sent and rsync is executing every 2 minutes, because something must have failed (a kind of whatchdog).

Comment: I also want to know if there is a more elegant solution, that's why I marked as favourite your question. But, at least, I also wanted to help with one way to solve this issue. Maybe in some days we can learn other ways of achieving this if anybody else answers. I prefer learning something useful than wining some points in here.